# How do I extrude faces along their actual normals?

Tags: modeling, extrude

Using 3.1, I'm trying to extrude 2 faces forming a small angle along their individual normals. I use `Face` --> `Extrude Individual Faces` which shows a tooltip: "Extrude each individual face separately along local normals":

[image]

However the normals are not used (and I don't see where the axis used for each face does come from). I tried to use the same command with only one face selected, the result is the same for this face. What is the problem?

In case this is relevant, the pivot point is set to `Median Point`.

Comment: In Object mode, try to apply the scale?

Comment: @moonboots: This works. Thanks. Seem to me this is a bug, a normal is a normal whatever the scale...?

Comment: you mean it should not take the scale into account for this kind of operation? In my opinion it makes sense as it's not the 1:1 scale

Comment: In v 3.2a, you can do this without apply scale.

Comment: @moonboots: Yes, the new face should be centered on the normal, which is invariant with the scale. Computing the axis in 1:1 scale is not consistent. Else the size of the new face should be the 1:1 size too.

Comment: it does extrude along the normals except the object is scaled so the extrusion appears squashed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In *Object* mode, apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding this as an explanation of how extrusion is done with a scaled object.

There is an inconstancy between the face normal displayed by the normal gizmo and the face normal used by the tool extruding along the normal. There are two normals for Blender.

[image]

From left to right:

- The scaled object
- Blender uses 1:1 scale to determine the face normal. As the object is not scaled with the same factor for X, Y and Z, the normal is different from the normal gizmo normal.
- Blender extrudes the face.
- Blender resets the object actual scale. So the face size matches with the actual scale, but the extrusion axis is not coincident with the current face normal.